# specialized ViewController crash in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsurl

I have received crashes from apple about my app and here is some details about the crash :

```
specialized ViewController.collectionView(UICollectionView,cellForItemAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

And it shows me the following line :

```
let url = NSURL(string: FullArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
```

I am using the `url` for SDWebImage to load images :

```
cell.photos.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, options: nil, completed: block)
```

Is it about the url ? i can't guess its happening because of what !

Comment: Do you know the contents of `FullArray`? It seems that the value at `indexPath.row` is nil at that location.

Comment: `FullArray` is `NSMutableArray` and i add Strings from another array into it when i get the response from JSON (`addObject`). @Caleb